# Why adjustment is needed when calculating Skewness and Kurtosis?

Tags: descriptive-statistics

Some packages such as Mathlab, Minitab and SigmaXL caluclate adjustment for skewness and kurtosis.

For example at:
https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Descriptive-Statistics.html

it is suggested that skewness() called with flag = 1 should perform adjustment.

> The adjusted skewness coefficient is obtained by replacing the sample
> second and third central moments by their bias-corrected versions.

For example:
[1.1, 3.345, 12.234, 11.945, 14.235, 16.876, 20.213, 11.001, 7.098, 21.234]

Unadjusted Skewness: -0.20037148980927325

Adjusted Skewness: -0.23761135723444532

Unadjusted Kurtosis: 2.0323918361135647

Adjusted Kurtosis: -0.7463072897278054

Please advice why such adjustment is needed and when?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compute the sample skewness, you need the first equation, which defines sample skewness as:

$\frac{\text{mean}((x - \text{mean}(x))^3)}{\text{std}(x)^3}$

If you want to estimate the population skewness, you use the second equation, which defines adjusted skewness as:

$\frac{\sqrt{N(N-1)}}{N-2} \times \frac{\text{mean}((x - \text{mean}(x))^3)}{\text{std}(x)^3}$

As is written on the page you link to: "The adjusted skewness coefficient is obtained by replacing the sample second and third central moments by their bias-corrected versions."

To estimate the population mean, we compute the sample mean and use $N$ as the denominator. To estimate the population variance, we compute the sample variance and use $N-1$ as the denominator. This is where the $\sqrt{N(N-1)}$ in the numerator comes from; it corrects for the bias due to using the sample mean as an estimator for the population mean.

To estimate the population skewness, we compute the sample skewness, and use $N-2$ as the denominator. This is where $N-2$ in the denominator comes from. $N-2$ is used because for computing skewness, we use both sample mean and variance, we have thus already used up two degrees of freedom. This is the bias corrected for.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when we compute "sample moments" these sample statistics are intended to be used as estimators of the underlying true moments of the distribution that they are intended to represent.  Just as with the sample variance, this means that there may be some adjustments made from just taking the average of the sum of power-deviations in the sample (e.g., for the sample variance we apply [Bessel's correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction) to obtain an unbiased estimator of the variance parameter).  For the higher moments like skewness and kurtosis, the adjustments become more complicated and there are some competing versions of these statistics in the literature.  Each type of "sample skewness" or "sample kurtosis" statistic is a suggested estimator for the underlying skewness and kurtosis of the distribution that they are intended to represent.

It is important to note that the different forms of a given sample moment will converge to one another as you get a large sample (i.e., the adjustments become smaller and smaller in the limit).  The difference in outcomes of these different forms tends to be largest when we have small samples, when it is inherently difficult to estimate higher-order moments.  We accept that with small samples there is substatial variability in different (but reasonable) estimators of the distribution moments.  The relative merits of the different forms depends heavily on the shape of the underlying distribution, which is of course unknown.

As to which adjustment is best, and when, that is a complicated question.  There are various proposals for the form of the "sample skewness" and "sample kurtosis" in the statistical literature and these have been compared using simulation analysis to get an idea of how they perform in estimation of the underlying distribution moments (see e.g., [Joanes and Gill 1998](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2988433)).  The linked paper will give you a good introduction to the different measures and simulation comparisons between them.  Ultimately, you can make a judgment on which form of the "sample skewness" and "sample kurtosis" you find to be a desirable estimator, based on the analysis in the statistical literature.  Any of the estimators used in the linked paper are reasonable estimators, with some minor advantages/disadvantages relative to one another in certain cases.